# Angular daterange picker get selected range name

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using [Date Range Picker for Angular and Bootstrap](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker) and having settings same as below

```
$scope.opts = {
                locale: {
                    applyClass: 'btn-green',
                    applyLabel: "Apply",
                    fromLabel: "From",
                    format: "D MMMM YYYY",
                    toLabel: "To",
                    cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
                    customRangeLabel: 'Custom range'
                },
                ranges: {
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                    'Last 14 Days': [moment().subtract(13, 'days'), moment()],
                    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()]
                },
                opens: 'left',
                eventHandlers: {
                    'apply.daterangepicker': function (ev, picker) {

                    }
                }
            };
```

While selecting any option from the defined ranges or custom range.

```
ranges: {
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                    'Last 14 Days': [moment().subtract(13, 'days'), moment()],
                    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()]
                },
```

I want to get range name like **Last 7 Days, Last 14 Days or custom range**

Is there any way to get this without calculating difference from selected dates?